# Zero downtime Google Compute Engine (GCE) deployment

Tags: deployment, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy this docker GCE project in a `deploy.yaml` but every time I update my git repository, the server goes down due to 1.
The original instance being deleted and 2. The new instance hasn't finished starting up yet (or at least the web app hasn't finished starting up yet).

What command should I use or how should I change this so that I have a canary deployment that destroys the old instances once a new one is up (I only have one instance running at a time)? I have no health checks on the instance group, only the load balancer.

```yaml
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['compute', 'instance-groups', 'managed', 'rolling-action', 'replace', 'a-group', '--max-surge', '1']
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the instance group size? Try setting --max-unavailable=0 OR resize the instance group by one before the replace operation.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley ! The max-unavailable parameter worked (with a health check enabled on the instance group)! Out of curiosity, is the `--max-unavailable=0` parameter something you'd recommend for multiple instances? Or would you recommend the resize?

Comment: There is a tradeoff when upgrading (replacing) an instance group. A rolling update means that there are old and new versions of your application running. Plus the issue of availability (number of instances handling traffic). Finally, there is the total time to replace all instances. In your case, `--max-unavailable=0` probably meets your goals because it prevents the issue of no available instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like John said - you can set [`max-unavailable`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable) and [`max-surge`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-surge) variables to alter the behavior of your deployment during updates.